# Is overflow Menu shows the image and text at a time

Tags: android

I want to show the image and text in overflow menu in Actionbar. I gave the all tags in

```
    res\menu\main.xml.
```

But both image and text are not visible at a time.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_websearch"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="ALl"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_websearch1"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Flowers"/>
   <item
    android:id="@+id/action_websearch2"
    android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Fruits"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard overflow menu does not show the icons. Those are just used if the item is shown in the ActionBar.